# How to open Selenium Browser in User mode, not in robotic window

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I have written selenium code and it opens Firefox browser, but the browser it opens appears to be similar in behaviour to a private window, i.e., it does not load user login sessions from the normal Firefox browser, neither does it store sessions once closed. I want to open selenium as if it was operated by a human, in the original Firefox, that does not contain the icon: [image]

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your User-Profile see:

- [Firefox User-Profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data#w_how-do-i-find-my-profile)

Now you can add Options to your WebDriver.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/path/to/my/profile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
```

This should load the previous saved User-Profile.